# How to make Mongoose Schema id generate a 16 digits random number

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm new to mongoose. I'm creating a model (creditnote) that consists of a 16 digits unique reference (serves as primary key) and an integer that represents the number of credits.

I want the reference to be the model's id and to be an auto-generated 16 digits number. How can I achieve this?

Right now I have the following code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
// Setup schema
var creditnoteSchema = mongoose.Schema({
reference: {
    type: mongoose.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    default: function(){
        // Generate 16 digits random number
        number = (Math.random()+' ').substring(2,10)+(Math.random()+' ').substring(2,10);

    }
},
amount: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    validate: {
        validator: Number.isInteger,
        message: '{VALUE} is not an integer value'
    }
}

});
```

Comment: You should `return` the number you generated from the function. Also your function is probably not collision resistant and doesn't guarantee the length of 16 digits.

Comment: @thammada Completely forgot the return. I saw somewhere on stackoverflow that this function guarantees the 16 digits. Any idea how to make it collision resistant?

Answer (score 1):

All objects created in MongoDB have a property `_id` which serves as a unique ID. You can also use `ObjectId` to generate a unique key, like this:

```
const {ObjectId} = require('mongodb'); 
console.log(ObjectId());
```